# Laravel scout, при индексации данных получаю ошибку Driver [elasticsearch] not supported

Tags: laravel, docker, elasticsearch

Поднял на докере проект ларавел + эластик, при попытке сделать индексы выдает ошибку что Driver [elasticsearch] not supported.

в .env указал конфиги так:

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=elasticsearch
SCOUT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=http://localhost:9200/
SCOUT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
```

в scout.php

```
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'elasticsearch'),
```

в docker-compose.yml

```
elasticsearch:
 image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
 environment:
  - discovery.type=single-node
 ports:
  - 9200:9200
 networks:
  - laraelastic
```

Вызываю в консоле: `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\YourModel"`
В ответ получаю: `Driver [elasticsearch] not supported.`

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было указать название контейнера подсети, который в docker-compose.yml, и его порт, примерно так: SCOUT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch:9200